# JSON response format - Remove the reference of the result

Tags: java, json

I have the following format for the JSON response:

```
{
  "showItems" :
  [
    {
      "errorMsg" : "NoRecordsFound",
      "response" : "failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I format my response where I want to remove the reference to result refer format below?

```
{
  [
    {
      "errorMsg" : "NoRecordsFound",
      "response" : "failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I used any library or any other approach?

Comment: the result that you want is, not a valid json format.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [JSON.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) in C#:

```
string json = "{\"showItems\":[{\"errorMsg\":\"NoRecordsFound\",\"response\":\"failed\"}]}";
dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

and just serialize the showItems array:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.showItems);
```

result is:

```
[
  {
      "errorMsg": "NoRecordsFound",
      "response": "failed"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can I use this library with Java, can you give one more example with java

Answer (score 0):

Result JSON you want has incorrect format and cannot be applied and used by JSON parsers.

The only way if you want to keep array item is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "errorMsg" : "NoRecordsFound",
      "response" : "failed"
    }
  ]
]
```

i.e. to use an array as a root element.

BTW you can check json format in any online parsers, e.g. http://json.parser.online.fr